# Winsock2.h: FD_SET: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

Tags: gcc, warnings, mingw, winsock2

Excerpt from winsock2.h:

```
#define FD_SET(fd, set) do { u_int __i;\
for (__i = 0; __i < ((fd_set *)(set))->fd_count ; __i++) {\
    if (((fd_set *)(set))->fd_array[__i] == (fd)) {\
        break;\
    }\
}\
if (__i == ((fd_set *)(set))->fd_count) {\
    if (((fd_set *)(set))->fd_count < FD_SETSIZE) {\
        ((fd_set *)(set))->fd_array[__i] = (fd);\
        ((fd_set *)(set))->fd_count++;\
    }\
}\
} while(0)
```

I am passing in `fd` of type `int` and `set` of type `fd_set *`. It looks like the cause of the warning may originate from the #define for `FD_SETSIZE`. Another excerpt from the same header:

```
#ifndef FD_SETSIZE
#define FD_SETSIZE  64
#endif
```

I redefined `FD_SETSIZE` to `64U` prior to including winsock2.h but this doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fd` should be of type `SOCKET` which is `u_int`.

The relevant line from the macro was:

`if (((fd_set *)(set))->fd_array[__i] == (fd)) {`

Didn't occur to me that `==` is a comparison operator for whatever reason.